# E4 support Help, editor and view management, text editors, resource views, preference?

Tags: plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4, eclipse-3.6

I am create pure E4 RCP Application but E4 support Help, editor and view management, text editors, resource views, preference and properties or not ? and how to support? any other solution ?

i am confusing E3 use or E4 in my application ?

Please help me friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write all that yourself with a pure e4 application.

The JFace code provides some code for preferences, properties and text editors but it is not as advanced as the Eclipse code.

If you want to use the things you mention you should write a 3.x compatibility mode RCP.